# Intriguing Equation

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, roots

How many ordered tuples of 7 integers ${\{x_{i}\}}_{i=1}^{7}$ are there, such that
$$\sum _{i=1}^{7}{x_{i}}-\prod_{i=1}^{7}{x_{i}} =6$$
where $1\le x_i\le 8$.

> I tried taking ${ \{ x_{ i }\}  }_{ i=1 }^{ 7 }$ to be roots of a septic equation and then tried Vieta's Formula but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing $x_i$ as $1 + y_i$, we have

$$\prod_{i=1}^7 x_i = \prod_{i=1}^7 (1+y_i) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^7 y_i + \sum_{1\le i < j \le 7} y_i y_j + \cdots$$

If more than one $x_i > 1$, the non-linear terms in RHS will be positive. This will lead to

$$\prod_{i=1}^7 x_i > 1 + \sum_{i=1}^7 y_i = \sum_{i=1}^7 x_i - 6$$

and hence cannot be a solution of the problem. This leaves us to look at the remaining 50 7-tuples where at most one of the $x_i > 1$.

- one 7-tuple with $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_7 = 1$.
- seven 7-tubles with $x_1 > 1, x_2 = \cdots = x_7 = 1$.
- seven 7-tubles with $x_2 > 1, x_1 = x_3 = \cdots = x_7 = 1$.
- etc, etc..

It is easy to see all these 7-tuples are solutions of the problem. i.e. the number of solution is $50$.